# Application hangs when getting PrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket

Tags: .net, wpf, printing

I have a WPF application which hangs exactly when getting the default PrintTicket...

```
PrintTicket printTicket = printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Can you show us the calling code?

Comment: Post the call stack, with unmanaged debugging and the source server enabled.

Comment: Solved after removing and adding again the printer. It appears to be some kind of printer driver bug.